# Problems obtaining the correct object class. R

Tags: r, function, class

I created a small function to process a dataframe to be able to use the function:

```
preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles()
```

Since normalize.quintles() can only use a matrixc object, and I need to rearrange my data, I create a small function that takes a specific column (variable) in a especific data frame and do the following:

```
normal<-function(boco,df){
  df_p1<-subset(df,df$Plate==1)
  df_p2<-subset(df,df$Plate==2)
  mat<-cbind(df_p1$boco,df_p2$boco)
  norm<-preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles(mat)
  df_1<-data.frame(var_1=c(norm[,1],norm[,2]),well=c(df_p1$well,df_p2$well))
  return(df_1)
}
```

However, "mat" should be a matrix, but it seems the cbind() does not do its job since I'm obtaining the following Error:

```
normal(antitrombina_FI,Six_Plex_IID)

Error in preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles(mat) : 
  Matrix expected in normalize.quantiles
```

So, it is clear that the cbind() is not creating a matrix. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: `cbind` is an S3-class method. There is a method for both `matrix` and `data.frame` so if the input is `data.frame` the output will also be `data.frame`. You could try to use `as.matrix` on your `mat` object.

Comment: If you need more help than Oliver's good recommendation, please share enough data to make a small reproducible example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Oliver, I tried that, it does not work. I'm not sure why but it does not create a matrix, it does some weird things. I also not sure if your statement is true. I can create matrix from data frames using cbind. however I dont know why, inside the function it creates a df not a matrix...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are binding two NULL objects together, yielding NULL, which is not a matrix. If your `df` objects are `data.frame`, then `df_p1$boco` is interpreted as "extract the variable named `boco`", not "extract the variable whose name is the value of an object having the symbol `boco`". I suspect that your data does not contain a variable literally named "boco", so `df_p1$boco` is evaluated as NULL.

If you want to extract the column that is given as the value to the formal argument `boco` in function `normal()` then you should use `[[`, not `$`:

```
normal<-function(boco,df){
  df_p1<-subset(df,df$Plate==1)
  df_p2<-subset(df,df$Plate==2)
  mat<-cbind(df_p1[[boco]],df_p2[[boco]])
  norm<-preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles(mat)
  df_1<-data.frame(var_1=c(norm[,1],norm[,2]),well=c(df_p1$well,df_p2$well))
  return(df_1)
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this answer. Very good guess, I bet you're right!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help bcarlsen. However I have found some errors:

First, I believe you need to introduce quotes in

```
mat<-cbind(df_p1[["boco"]],df_p2[["boco"]])
```

If I run this script outside of a function works erally perfectly:

```
df_p1<-subset(Six_Plex_IID,Six_Plex_IID$Plate==1)
df_p2<-subset(Six_Plex_IID,Six_Plex_IID$Plate==2)
mat<-cbind(df_p1[["antitrombina_FI"]],df_p2[["antitrombina_FI"]])
norm<-preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles(mat)
```

However If I introduce this now in a function and try to run it like a function:

```
normal<-function(boco,df){
  df_p1<-subset(df,df$Plate==1)
  df_p2<-subset(df,df$Plate==2)
  mat<-cbind(df_p1[["boco"]],df_p2[["boco"]])
  norm<-preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles(mat)
  df_1<-data.frame(var_1=c(norm[,1],norm[,2]),well=c(df_p1$well,df_p2$well))
  return(df_1)
}
normal(antitrombina_FI,Six_Plex_IID)
```

I get the same error mesage:

```
Error in preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles(mat) : 
  Matrix expected in normalize.quantiles
```

I'm completely clueless about why this is happening, why outside the function I'm obtaining a matrix and why inside the function not.

Thanks

Comment: Do not put `boco` in quotes within `[[` in the function. `normal(antitrombina_FI,Six_Plex_IID)` is `normal(boco = antitrombina_FI, df = Six_Plex_IID)`; i.e. `antitrombina_FI` is matched to the formal argument `boco` of normal(). The *value* of the symbol `boco` *within your function call* is the character vector "antitrombina_FI". `df_p1[["boco"]]` means "get the variable *named* "boco" from the object df_p1". This is NULL, as there's no variable *named* "boco" in df_p1. df_p1 does have a variable named "antitrombina_FI", which is the *value* of the object `boco` within the function scope.

Comment: `df_p1[["boco"]]` = get variable of `df_p1` with the name "boco". If there is no variable literally named "boco" on `df_p1` this returns NULL.

`df_p1[[boco]]` = get variable of `df_p1` with a name that is equal to the value of the object `boco`. If there is no object `boco` in an accessible environment this will throw an exception. There's an object with the symbol `boco` within the function because `boco` is the name of one of the formal arguments.

`cbind(NULL, NULL)` returns NULL. `normalize.quantiles(cbind(NULL, NULL))` throws an exception because NULL is not a matrix.